# Cannot access mysql database from node express app

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I know this has been answered a lot but none of them seem to help me in this problem. I want to create a create-react-app client, express backend and mysql database with docker-compose. I have configured my file which seems to spin up all of my containers on the givens ports. My problem is that when I try to access my database using the npm package mysql that I get a `ECONNREFUSED` error. I know I can connect to the database from a node app as when I create a separate node app that is not in a docker container it works fine.

Why would I be able to access my docker container mysql database from Sequel Pro and from another non docker node app but not when I am running them all using docker-compose.

Heres a link to my docker-compose file here. https://github.com/Jazilch/airbnb-app/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

[image]

I removed the user and password as I know they are correct as I can connect using the same username and password from my other node server that is using the same configuration.

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '3306',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: 'airbnb_database',
});

pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query);

pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) {
      if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
          console.error('Database connection was closed.')
      }
      if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
          console.error('Database has too many connections.')
      }
      if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
          console.error('Database connection was refused.')
      }
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }
  }
  if (connection) connection.release()
  return
})
```

Comment: where is the code that generates the error? How exactly are you trying to connect? That part is not in your github repository

Comment: @Mihai I added some additional code of how I connecting to the database above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `localhost` with the name of the database container. I suggest you add nicer names with `container_name` in your docker-compose.yml and use that name.

For example for the mysql service:

```
   container_name: mysql
```

and in your script:

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'mysql',
  port: '3306',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: 'airbnb_database',
});
```

You also have an error in your docker-compose.yml where the databse is on a different network than the 'api'. This way they will never see each other. To correct, the mysqldb service should look like this:

```
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
    networks:
      - webappnetwork
```

Comment: That makes sense. I added the `container_name` into my yml file but I seem to be getting the following error now. 
`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mysql mysql:3306`
http://prntscr.com/nm384b

Comment: this is weird.... Can you do me a favor and open a shell in the api container and run "ping mysql" in there?

Comment: Did you mean just from my api folder where my node app should be running.Looks like I get the following `ping: cannot resolve mysql: Unknown host`. http://prntscr.com/nm3f1j

Comment: I got it sorry. I had to clone the project and run it on my own. You create a network and you attach the api container to that network. But you don't attach the mysql container. They need to be on the same network! Either remove that network all together or put the mysql container as well on the same network.

Comment: @JamesZilch I updated the solution with this finding as well

Comment: Thank you so much. Thats exactly what it was. I added the network to my mysql database service and now it is working.